# How to use And Or Filters in powershell where-object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of properties of AD user objects.  Most of the script works except the "where-object" filters are applied.  I want to get all users who meet the following:  LastLogonDate is more than 75 days ago (this works), enabled (this works) AND either of the following - account expires in the future or never expires.  $when is defined properly.

I've tried a number of options and I typically get no output or one or the other in the output.

```
| Where-Object{($_.lastlogondate -le $When -AND $_.enabled -eq $True) -AND Where-Object($_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date) -OR $_.AccountExpirationDate -eq 0)} |
```

I should see accounts with expiry dates in the future AND accounts that do not expire, but I'm having problems with the "This AND this AND (this OR this)"

Comment: you cannot chain `Where-Object` like that. [*grin*] you need to either pipe from one tot he next OR use a compound set of criteria in _one_ W-O stage.

Comment: also, calling `Get-Date` in the pipeline like that will slow things down - it gets called once per item. [*grin*] calc that value before you enter the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The extra `Where-Object` in your code should throw an error...

```
    Where-Object {
            $_.lastlogondate -le $When -AND 
            $_.enabled -eq $True -AND 
            ($_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date) -OR $_.AccountExpirationDate -eq 0)
    }
```

This should work if your input is correct.

Comment: This is what I used originally, but it doesn't return accounts that are set to never expire.  This returns -enabled = true, -lastlogondate is blank (for some reason I don't understand, since I didn't specify that), and the future account expiration date.

Comment: I ended up getting exactly what I needed using `$null`,what I thought I had used before.  Here is what works:

````Where-Object {$_.enabled -eq $True -AND $_.lastlogondate -le $When -AND ($_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date) -OR $_.AccountExpirationDate -eq $null)}````